# Google API: markers not showing up on arraytable on map (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-api

I used `arraytodatatable` and tried to showed my data on the map, but I did not see any markers on the map.

Here is the code that I used

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Charts Tutorial</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = 
"https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = 
"https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['map'],'mapsApiKey': 'my 
API'});     
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 
0 
auto">
</div>
<script language = "JavaScript">

function drawChart() {
// Define the chart to be drawn.
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],
[37.4232, -122.0853, 'Work'],
[37.4289, -122.1697, 'University'],
[37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport'],
[37.4422, -122.1731, 'Shopping']
]);

// Set chart options
var options = {
showTip: true,
};      

// Instantiate and draw the chart.
var chart = new 
google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('container'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error message I got was:

```
maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png:1 GET 
file://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png 
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Does this mean the image that marker used does not exist anymore? If so, is there a way for me to change the color the marker so I can get the problem fixed?